# Função circle, como mandar o parametro centro?

Tags: opencv

Estou mandando o parametro centro dado por (2953,1999) como mostro a seguir:

```
circle(imgOr,(2953,1999),224,Scalar(255,0,0));
```

Mas da o erro:

> could not convert (0,1999) from 'int' to 'cv::Point'

Comment: Deu certo! Utilizei o CvPoint(2953,1999);

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar isto:

```
circle(imgOr,Point(2953,1999),224,Scalar(255,0,0));
```

só tem que tomar cuidado para que esse circulo não ultrapasse as bordas da imagem

Comment: Com Point também de erro, tive que usar o CvPoint, esses pontos e raios, já são dadas no próprio documento. São imagens de mamografias do MIAS